# Error when trying to play video in Xcode 7 / Swift 2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

I am trying to play a video inside a view controller when I enter it, but a get one error, listed below.Not too familiar with video playback, so is it supposed to be in a viewcontroller and how do I fix that error?The video is stored in xcode. Thanks.

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer
import AVFoundation

class AuroraViewController: UIViewController {



@IBOutlet var AuroraViewController: UIView!

var moviePlayer: AVPlayer?


private func playVideo() {
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Aurora", ofType:"mp4") {
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
```

The line below is where I get the error of: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

```
        moviePlayer = AVPlayer(contentURL: url) {
            self.moviePlayer = moviePlayer
            moviePlayer.AuroraViewController.frame = self.AuroraViewController.bounds
            moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()
            moviePlayer.scalingMode = .AspectFill
            self.AuroraViewController.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)
        }
    } else {
        debugPrint("Ops, something wrong when playing video.m4v")
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    playVideo()
}




override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



}
```

***UPDATE*** Correct code:

```
import UIKit 
import AVFoundation 
import AVKit 

class AuroraViewController: AVPlayerViewController { 
private func playVideo() { 
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Aurora", ofType: "mp4") { 
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path) 
        player = AVPlayer(URL: url) 
    } 
    else { 
        println("Oops, could not find resource Aurora.mp4") 
    } 
} 

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) { 
    super.viewDidAppear(animated) 
    playVideo() 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a 'total re-write'.

The following did the job:

Add "AVKit.framework" to the "Build Phases" -> "Link Binary With Libraries" in Project settings.

In Storyboard, change the identity of your `UIViewController` to be AuroraViewController.

The resulting code then is all that's needed:

```
import UIKit 
import AVFoundation 
import AVKit 

class AuroraViewController: AVPlayerViewController { 
    private func playVideo() { 
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Aurora", ofType: "mp4") { 
            let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path) 
            player = AVPlayer(URL: url) 
        } 
        else { 
            println("Oops, could not find resource Aurora.mp4") 
        } 
    } 

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) { 
        super.viewDidAppear(animated) 
        playVideo() 
    } 
}
```

Comment: See the braces `{` and `}` I quote above? Remove them from your code. Use auto-reindent if you're confused afterwards. Compile and be happy.

Comment: I don't get any errors but when i open the view controller in simulator, it is just a white screen

Comment: Huh? You just gave a compiler error in your question: "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Comment: You fixed the error but now the video won't show...just a white screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84717/discussion-between-yzet00-and-basezen).